# Question about "C++ Concurrency in Action" code

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I'm reading C++ `Concurrency In Action` and in page 32 (Chapter 2) there is this code.

```cpp
template <typename Iterator, typename T>
struct accumulate_block
{
    void operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last, T &result)
    {
        result = std::accumulate(first, last, result);
    }
};
template <typename Iterator, typename T>
T parallel_accumulate(Iterator first, Iterator last, T init)
{
    unsigned long const length = std::distance(first, last);
    if (!length)
        return init;
    unsigned long const min_per_thread = 25;
    unsigned long const max_threads = (length + min_per_thread - 1) / min_per_thread;
    unsigned long const hardware_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    unsigned long const num_threads = std::min(hardware_threads != 0 ? hardware_threads : 2, max_threads);
    unsigned long const block_size = length / num_threads;
    std::vector<T> results(num_threads);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_threads - 1);
    Iterator block_start = first;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < (num_threads - 1); ++i)
    {
        Iterator block_end = block_start;
        std::advance(block_end, block_size);
        threads[i] = std::thread(accumulate_block<Iterator, T>(),
                                 block_end, std::ref(results[i]));
        block_start = block_end;
    }
 accumulate_block<Iterator,T(block_start,last,results[num_threads-1]); 
 
 for(auto& entry: threads)
     entry.join(); 
 return std::accumulate(results.begin(),results.end(),init);
}
```

I don't understand some things.

1. Why did the author choose 25 as the `min_per_thread`? Is this just an arbitrary number or is there a thought  behing it?
2. I don't understand the formula in this piece of code:

```cpp
unsigned long const max_threads=
 (length+min_per_thread-1)/min_per_thread;
```

Why do we use this formula to find the "max threads" and what do we need it for?

I tried to search for other similar questions around this piece of code but found nothing.

Comment: 1. It is not worth it to start a new thread for just a few elements, so the author has supposedly run some tests and found that 25 per thread is a reasonable number.  2. That just rounds up to the next multiple of 25.

Comment: Which edition of the book are you using? I have the 1st and the 2nd edition and neither of them has this code on page 55.

Comment: @DanielLangr My bad. It is on page 32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why did the author choose 25 as the min_per_thread? Is this just an
> arbitrary number or is there a thought behing it?

The number `25` is an arbitrary number. You may use any number as you like.

> I don't understand the formula in this piece of code:

```
unsigned long const max_threads=
 (length+min_per_thread-1)/min_per_thread;
```

When you divide a number, for example `13` (`length`) by `4` (`min_per_thread`) you will get `3` due to the integer arithmetic. The remainder is equal to 1, so you provided only `3` threads for the three ranges `[0, 3]`, `[4,7]` and `[8, 11]`, but the element `12` is left without a thread. You need to provide a thread for the remainder.

You can write:

`13 + ( 4 - 1 )` that is equal to `16`, and `16` divided by `4` will yield `4`. Now all ranges included in the range for the remainder will have their own thread.

If, for example, `length` is equal to `12` then the added value `min_per_thread - 1` will not affect the required number of threads, equal to `3` in this case.

In general, the remainder can be any value in the range `[0, min_per_thread - 1]`.

Particulary, if `length` is less than `min_per_thread` then to use the expression without the operand `min_per_thread - 1` you will get that  `max_threads` will be equal to `0`, though one thread is required in any case.

Comment: The actual number of threads used for the algorithm run is `std::min(hardware_threads!=0?hardware_threads:2,max_threads)`. I believe that piece of code is there just to ensure that `max_threads` will not be 0 in case that `length` is lower than `min_per_thread`.

Comment: The discussion about one element not being covered by any thread and the fact that `max_threads` might end up being 0 both makes lots of sense.
Thanks to both!